# How to Activate tkinter textboxes via loop in tkinter python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have 20 text boxes which I created using tkinter-Python as shown below:

[image]

Now I have a list y1[]

If number of elements in y1 = 6,
6 text boxes should be activated

If number of elements in y1 = 3,
3 text boxes should be activated

How do I do this?

The below is what I've tried so far:

```
 if len(y1) <= 10:
   i = 0
   for i in range(len(y1)):
    if i == 1:
      txtbox1.config(state=NORMAL)       
      txtbox1.insert(0, y[0])     
     if i == 2:
      txtbox2.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox2.insert(0, y[0])
     if i == 3:
      txtbox3.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox3.insert(0, y[0])
     if i == 4:
      txtbox4.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox4.insert(0, y[0])
     if i == 5:
      txtbox5.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox5.insert(0, y[0])
     if i == 6:
      txtbox6.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox6.insert(0, y[0])
     if i == 7:
      txtbox7.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox7.insert(0, y[0])
     if i == 8:
      txtbox8.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox8.insert(0, y[0])
     if i == 9:
      txtbox9.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox9.insert(0, y[0])
     if i == 10:
      txtbox10.config(state=NORMAL)
      txtbox10.insert(0, y[0])
     i = i + 1
```

Comment: Mark an answer as solved if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the textboxes in an array and then iterate over array to enable/disable the specific number of textboxes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

N = 20
activated_text_boxes = random.randint(0, N)

window = tk.Tk()

text_boxes = [tk.Text(window, height=1, width=300) for i in range(N)]

for idx, tb in enumerate(text_boxes):
    tb.pack()
    print(tb)
    if idx < activated_text_boxes:
        print("normal")
        tb["bg"] = "blue"
        tb["state"] = "normal"
    else:
        print("disabled")
        tb["bg"] = "red"
        tb["state"] = "disabled"

window.mainloop()
```